# Does the question 'the car is arrived' grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

Can we use 'is' in the sentence to describe the meaning 'already'?

Comment: Unless *arrived* is being used in an odd way where *is arrived* might be possible, it's (1) the car *has* arrived, (2) the car *is* ***arriving***, or (3) the car *will* arrive. I suppose it depends on what you're trying to say. Note that all three of those tenses could be followed by *already*, if *already* is meant as an informal intensifier. (For example, "Put it down already!")

Comment: *Is* the question 'the car is arrived' grammatically correct?

Comment: There are multitudes of ways this can be answered, ranging from looking in the corpora of non-standard Englishes to consulting an introductory book on grammar. I'm afraid this question needs more focus.

Answer (score 1):

It's a statement, not a question. The use of phrases like *is come* to mean *has come* is grammatical, but very old-fashioned and would never be used in ordinary conversation.

Comment: Why is "the car is arrived" not correct and "the car is stolen" is correct?

Comment: Can't it be said in a passive voice or is there some rule about this?

Comment: _Is come_ is not the passive voice (_come_ and _ arrive_ are intransitive verbs). It's just an archaic way of saying _has come_. See https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2012/01/is-come.html

Answer (score 0):

No. 'Arrived' is the *past tense* of 'arrive', so you would not say it *is* arrived.

You could say:

> The car *has* arrived.

or

> The car *is here*.